# Cannot get a Perl regex to match this HTML

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a program to scan a `.txt` file with HTML that contains, for example

```
    title="Recent Announcements "
    height="475"
    width="100%"
    frameborder="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    marginheight="0"
    scrolling="auto"
    src="https://sample.url?panel=Main"
```

My Perl code looks like

```
if ( /title="Recent.*src="(.+[^\/]panel=Main)"/s ) {
  do stuff;
}
```

If I separate `(/title="Recent"/)` and `(/src="(.+[^\/]panel=Main)"/)` into two separate `if` statements, both checks work fine.

The problem is that there are multiple sections with that same format of `src=` in the `.txt` file and I want to use this method to capture *only* the URL after `title=Recent Announcements`.

Comment: I suspect you may be reading a line at a time and the title= and src= are on different lines; show more of your code to get good advice for what to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.*` and `.+` are greedy, meaning that if your input has several `title=...` and `src=...` lines, your regex will match from the first `title` to the last `src`. Try the non-greedy expressions `.*?` and `.+?`.

```
/title="Recent.*?src="(.+?[^\/]panel=Main)"/s
```

Comment: This is a *temporary solution*. Unless your data is trivial, you should parse it as HTML and extract the element you need that way.

Comment: @mob: *Please* never recommend a regex solution for parsing HTML. I have to -1 you

Comment: There is a difference between trying to *parse HTML* with regular expressions and pulling specific tags out. Regular expressions are perfectly suited for that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Its hard to do without knowing what those 'other sections' might be.

```
 #  /(?s)title\s*=\s*"Recent(?:(?!title\s*=\s*"Recent|src\s*=\s*").)+src\s*=\s*"([^"]*panel=Main)"/

 (?s)
 title \s* = \s* "Recent
 (?:
      (?!
           title \s* = \s* "Recent
        |  src \s* = \s* "
      )
      . 
 )+
 src \s* = \s* " 
 ( [^"]*  panel=Main )
 "
```